# Instantaneous creature death and checking conditions

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have a [Night of Souls' Betrayal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNight%5d%2b%5bof%5d%2b%5bSouls%27%5d%2b%5bBetrayal%5d), and so does my opponent. Creatures get -2/-2.

I have a [Marchesa, the Black Rose](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMarchesa%2c%20the%20Black%20Rose%5d), relevant text:

> Whenever a creature you control with a +1/+1 counter on it dies, return that card to the battlefield under your control at the beginning of the next end step.

I play a [Rakdos Cackler](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRakdos%20Cackler%5d), a 1/1 with Unleash.

If I choose to have Rakdos Cackler enter with a counter, will it have a +1/+1 counter on it when it dies? Will Marchesa's ability return Rakdos Cackler to the battlefield at the next end step?

Comment: What part of this interaction are you unsure about? Do you want to know whether the Cackler has a counter when it dies, or whether it dies at all, or something else?

Comment: If it will be reanimated when it dies

Comment: As in, will it have a +1/+1 counter when it dies

Comment: OK, I tried editing your question to make sure that point is emphasized.

Comment: Night of Soul's Betrayel is Legendary. How can there be two copies in play?

Comment: @steenbergh As of M14, each player can have his or her own copy of a legendary permanent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will trigger every time it returns.

Let's start when the Cackler is on the stack, when you originally cast it.

If no one has a response, it resolves. When it is resolving, you choose whether or not to have it enter with a counter. Assuming you do, it enter with a counter on it, as a 0/0, because of the [Night of Souls' Betrayal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNight%5d%2b%5bof%5d%2b%5bSouls%27%5d%2b%5bBetrayal%5d)s.

At this point, state based actions are checked. The Cackler dies, but Marchesa will see it with a +1/+1 on it, and this process will repeat every end step.

Comment: [mtg:] card links don't work if there's an apostrophe in the card name.

Comment: @GendoIkari They actually do, as of a recent site update. Or at least they did, very recently.

Comment: @murgatroid99 They aren't working for me...

Comment: @diego Thanks, I see. Great to see that's finally been fixed!

Comment: It might be useful to point out that Unleash is a replacement effect, which is why the Cackler enters the battlefield with a counter, and that this is different from a triggered ability, like on [mtg: Bond Beetle].